# How to load weights into a model haveing different architecture in keras

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, keras-layer

I have two models with two different architecture. One of the model in multi input model and another one is single input model. Is it possible to save weights from  multi input model and load into another single input model in keras.

Comment: If you want to use a multi-input model's weights for a single input model, assuming your multi inputs are `X1, X2, X3, ..., Xn` and the single input is `X`, you would need to feed X to each `Xi` (where, `i = 1, 2, 3, ... , n`).

Comment: can you please provide some example and will it work when multiple inputs are images with different dimensions.

Comment: Hi @Shaleel Considering the shape of filters in the single model is the same as the multi-input model, you can just copy the weights layerwise and put it into the single model. If you provide some sample code of your models, I can elaborate. Thanks.